# Grouping items based on its list of elements similarity

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table with items following like items:

[image]

I would like to group Group ID's which has the exact same keys's.

Is it possible with LINQ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, simply use `GroupBy` and `ToDictonary` in Linq

```
var result = _dbcontext.YourTable
                       .GroupBy(item => item.GroupID)
                       .ToDictionary(i => i.key, i => i.Select(k => k.KeyID).ToList());
```

The result is `Dictionary<int, List<int>>` where the key is the `GroupID` and the value is List of KeyIDs which have the same GroupID